# Can't create JPA tables into derby with glassfish3

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink, glassfish-3, derby

I am trying to create clone database(s) with JPA (2.0) into derby from a legacy database. The JPA entities were generated from an existing database (by JDidea tools I think), and now I am using Eclipse + GlassFish3 + EclipseLink + Derby + JDK 6 to clone that database for secure development (and testing).

However I am getting into glassfish log these messages:

```
INFO: EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461
INFO: file:/C:/siilo/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/eclipseApps/omaasiointi-web/WEB-INF/classes/PU_NAME login successful
WARNING: Multiple [2] JMX MBeanServer instances exist, we will use the server at index [0] : [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@22beebcd].
WARNING: JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@22beebcd] from index [0] 
WARNING: JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@62ccf439] from index [1] 

WARNING: PER01000: Got SQLException executing statement "CREATE TABLE "postikoodi" ("lrivino" BIGINT NOT NULL, "szkielikoodi" VARCHAR(255), "szkuntakoodi" VARCHAR(255), "szpostinumero" VARCHAR(255), "szpostitoimipaikka" VARCHAR(255), "sztimestamp" VARCHAR(255), "szuserid" VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY ("lrivino"))": java.sql.SQLException: Table/View 'postikoodi' already exists in Schema 'APP'.
...
```

And there is a lot of these messages. There is multiple databases used, which are identical and the EclipseLink assumably tries to create all the tables in all the databases (for what reason I suppose I get enormous amounts of these errors => they seem to be about the same).

I created couple of database connections in Eclipse and checked that the 'APP' schema was empty in these, so I do not quite understand the error.

In persistence.xml I have the following defined:

```
<persistence-unit name="PU_NAME" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/__default</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.DerbyPlatform"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Any advice?

Comment: How are you check that the tables do not exist?  Make sure you are connecting to the same instance as the datasource is configured to access.  Since you are using drop+create options, it would suggest there are existing tables that the generated DDL script is incapable of dropping.  Please note that Glassfish intercepts the properties you've set and has EclipseLink generate scripts which Glassfish then uses to drop and create the tables, referred to as the Java2DB feature.  You might want to check the script it is using from the previous deploy, or that all PUs use different tables.

Comment: I made a connection to the Derby with the Eclipse (Using the data source explorer) and viewed the contents from there. I made 3 connections to different databases (total of 24 I think). None had any content. I received the same errors from all of the PUs / DB connections it used. (Didn't check every line as there were at least several hundred or maybe even thousands error messages)